# eglGetDisplay() throw exception

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to Initialize EGL with:

```
 #include <GLES3\gl3.h>
#include <EGL\egl.h>
#include <EGL\eglext.h>
void main(){
EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay (EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
}
```

I got no error from compiling it but it crashed when i run it. When i try to debug it the eglGetDisplay throw the exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7563CB49 in OpenGLES Examples.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

I have searched around but still no solution, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using headers and libraries from ARM Mali SDK instead of AMD SDK. I still don't know how but it works for me.